getDataExtensions: $search is a required parameter
I am trying to run the getDataExtensions REST API method to get a list of all Data Extensions inside a Business Unit.
When I run the request in Postman, the error message is

$search is a required parameter

This is understandable because the method should retrieve "a list of data extensions that match a search string."
However, I don't find any documentation on how to use this parameter, and how we retrieve a list of all Data Extensions.
UPDATE: I am experimenting and using request URIs such as this. They sometimes give some results, but I cannot find the logic behind it. Is this documented anywhere?
https://{{REST_ENDPOINT}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/data/v1/customobjects?$search=name=


Yes you are correct... after trying we get this error, if we try to fetch WITHOUT passing value to $search  or categoryId   .... {     "message": "A valid categoryId or $search parameter is required to retrieve CustomObjects.",     "errorcode": 10005,     "documentation": "" }

It is in fact super simple to start using those URL parameters. The important part is to understand how your chosen API call expects you to append them.
In your case:
Method: GET
URL: https://{subdomain}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/data/v1/customobjects?$search=''
Headers:
Authorization - Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
Content-Type - application/json

Then paste the name of a Data Extension you are trying to retrieve between the single quotes at the very end of the URL. Consider that this search works with the operator like and not is equal to, which means that a request like that $search='DE_' will result in finding those Data Extension names: DE_1, DE_2.

I would recommend getting familiar with those pages to understand better how to use URL parameters (examples are applicable for Assets only):

Simple Query
Advanced Query

